Error: mat-form-field must contain aN MatFormFieldControl
I try to implement an example for chips in angular, but I face an error on my console : ERROR: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl. I have declared what I need as a module to skip this error as I read on different solution. This is my import list in my principal module : imports:
BrowserModule,
AppRoutingModule,
BrowserAnimationsModule,
FormsModule,
MatInputModule,
MatChipsModule,
MatFormFieldModule,
MatSlideToggleModule
My final target is to bind between my dropdownlist and the chips to display what i select in my list !

please share the minimal reproducible code
